# I am asking a help where I am trying to build a approval system with list and workflow

Tags: sharepoint-list

I am asking a help where I am trying to build a approval system with list and workflow.  My problem is I have a list which need to have two fields which are like ' Core project tem' and 'hrs'.  The problem is I need to add multiple people on the ' Core Project team' field and then enter their corresponding 'hrs'.
I find it difficuly to think through list. What option available.
Thanks
Jose

Answer (score 0):

Their hours should be all the same. You can use multiple people column.
If hours is different add them one by one in the list.